# Xcode and data - 'cloud' or local?

Tags: xcode

I am new to learning xcode, and started a simple project which main goal is for me learn Xcode.
The project is a simple app that keeps track of scores in a cardgame. 
Sofar it is just for fun, for me and the guys I play cards with.

But heres an issue:
I would like to make it possible that it doesnt matter whose Iphone we are using.
Anyone with the app should be able to log in and see all of our gamescores.

That should be easy. Me and my friends could create a group, in which all of our games are stored.

Other people can create their own group, inwhich they can store theirs.

BUT where should I store the data, when building the app?

Potentially there could be a LOT of data, if a lot of people downloads the app, and plays a lot of cards!

I am a webprogrammer, and am used to working with PHP and mySQL.

Whats the smart way to deal with this?

Thanks
John

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the GameKit framework, might be best suited for your needs.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH1-SW1

Comment: Thanks. I already read a little about it. Im not too keen on getting this particular project as part of the game center. I would like it to be 'separate' from the 'games'. Hard to explain. It is a feel-thing. Playing cards is not 'gaming', and to some cardplayers that is important. They dont want to be 'gamers' and wouldnt dream of opening anything in the game center. :-D

Comment: Any other suggestions or advice for me?